# Recursion stackoverflow Java

Tags: java, recursion

I need to count the number of numbers on the right that are less than the number arr[i]. My problem is that the stack overflows at large sizes and I can't solve it in any way. Please tell me how can I refactor my code to avoid the error StackOverflow ?

```
public class Smaller {
    public static int[] smaller(int[] unsorted) {
        int[] result = new int[unsorted.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < unsorted.length; i++) {
            result[i] = countSmaller(unsorted[i], 0, i + 1, unsorted);
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static int countSmaller(int currentNumber, int count, int index, int[] arr) {
        if (index >= arr.length) {
            return count;
        }

        return arr[index] < currentNumber
                ? countSmaller(currentNumber, count + 1, index + 1, arr)
                : countSmaller(currentNumber, count, index + 1, arr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is recursion a requirement? An iterative solution seems more logical.

Comment: The iterative solution is not suitable in terms of execution time, so I thought why not try it with recursion.

Comment: As far as I can tell, your recursive solution is very similar to an iterative solution but with the overhead of recursion.

Comment: I would create a `SortedList` class that automatically sorts numbers added to it. Then as you go through the array, add the array items to the list and use that list to count how many less than.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with comments questioning whether recursion is your best solution here, but if it's a requirement you can avoid stack overflow by chopping subproblems in half rather than whittling them down one-by-one. The logic is that the count in the remaining data will be the sum of the count in the first half plus the count in the second half of the remaining data. This reduces the stack growth from O(n) to O(log n).

I originally did a Python implementation due to not having a Java compiler installed (plus my Java skills being rusty), but found an online java compiler at tutorialspoint.com. Here's an implementation of the divide and conquer logic described in the previous paragraph:

```java
public class Smaller {
    public static int[] smaller(int[] unsorted) {
        int[] result = new int[unsorted.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < unsorted.length; i++) {
            result[i] = countSmaller(unsorted[i], i+1, unsorted.length-1, unsorted);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static int countSmaller(int threshold, int start, int end, int[] unsorted) {
        if (start < end) {
            int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;
            int count = countSmaller(threshold, start, mid, unsorted);
            count += countSmaller(threshold, mid+1, end, unsorted);
            return count;
        } else if ((start == end) && (unsorted[start] < threshold)) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

With O(log n) stack growth, this should be able to handle ridonculously big arrays. Since the algorithm as a whole is O(n<sup>2</sup>), run time will limit you long before recursive stack limitations will.

#### Original Python Implementation

Sorry for showing this in Python, but I don't have a Java compiler and I didn't want to risk non-functioning code. The following does the trick and should be easy for you to translate:

```python
def smaller(unsorted):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(unsorted)):
        result.append(countSmaller(unsorted[i], i+1, len(unsorted)-1, unsorted))
    return result

def countSmaller(threshold, start, end, unsorted):
    if start < end:
        mid = start + (end - start) // 2    # double slash is integer division
        count = countSmaller(threshold, start, mid, unsorted)
        count += countSmaller(threshold, mid+1, end, unsorted)
        return count
    elif start == end and unsorted[start] < threshold:
        return 1
    return 0

data = [10, 9, 8, 11, 7, 6]
print(smaller(data))    # [4, 3, 2, 2, 1, 0]

print(smaller([]))      # []

print(smaller([42]))    # [0]
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but unfortunately the site gave me "Execution Timed Out (16000 ms)". It probably makes sense to try to look for some other solutions. I was trying to solve this with nested loops, which I don't think is good, and ran into the same error as I am now. I'm in confusion.

Comment: @Mark Your question was "Please tell me how can I refactor my code to avoid the error StackOverflow". I've done that. As mentioned in my answer your overall approach has O(n^2) run time, which is true whether it's done iteratively or recursively, so I can't say I'm surprised that you're getting timeouts. I explicitly stated "run time will limit you long before recursive stack limitations will", but your question was not about run time issues.

Comment: I understood you perfectly, I mean, in general, I'm somewhat confused how to get around this. I tried to work with your option, while I have not yet found the right solution, but I will definitely find it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Mark It means you need a completely different approach, which is a different question than the one you asked here. Try posting it as a different question, and put the focus on finding a better algorithm to improve the run time rather than on refactoring the recursion to prevent stack overflow.

Comment: @Mark Meanwhile, you hopefully got a few pieces of info here: 1) to avoid recursive stack overflows, chop problems into halves rather than reducing by 1; 2) substituting recursion for iteration will generally not yield a faster solution; and 3) substantial speedups come from improved algorithms, not improved implementations.

Comment: Yes, I got it! Thank you, I really did not know this, since I'm just learning, but I will definitely take the information you give to think about a new solution.